# xaml window background + dockpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

i want to create a Mainwindow with an background and a dockpanel. The background works fine when i comment the dock panel but when i uncomment it there will be no background shown. Why is that and what i have to chance to make it work ?
I just tryed to use grid.background but it works the same way. dockpanel uncommented= no background.

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/Magic2.png"/>
</Window.Background>

<Grid>
<DockPanel>
     <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
           <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="New" Click="mnuNew_Click"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Open"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Save"></MenuItem>
          </MenuItem>
     </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Menu fills up the entire the available space. You could set the Background property of the MenuItem to Transparent:

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/Magic2.png"/>
</Window.Background>

<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Transparent">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="New"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Open"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Save"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Uhm ... or solve the actual problem and make sure the menu doesn't span over the entire window (set the menu's height, e.g. `Height="23"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked